# Palindrome String VarArgs - Java (No Array just VarArgs)

Tags: java, methods, palindrome

I am a student trying to get this palindrome checker to reflect back if the entered strings are indeed a palindrome or not. I keep returning just one result and I cannot figure out why. Not sure if I am missing something from my loop or if I have something incorrect in my loop here.

```
public  class Palindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Palindrome Checker:  ");
        palindromChecker("aabaa", "cat", "racecar", "dog", "Madam");
    }

    public static void palindromChecker(String... values) {
        String stbr = "";
        String reverse = " ";

        for (int i = stbr.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            reverse += stbr.charAt(i);

        if (reverse.equalsIgnoreCase(stbr))
            System.out.println("This is a Palindrome");
        else {
            System.out.println("This is NOT a Palindrome");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You're not using the argument `values` inside your `palindromChecker` method. You're reversing `strb`, an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually looping through the input values from your array `values`. What you are doing is trying to reverse `stbr` which you assigned to be an empty String. You want to do something like this:

```
public class Palindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Palindrome Checker:  ");
        palindromChecker("aabaa", "cat", "racecar", "dog", "Madam");
    }

    public static void palindromChecker(String... values) {
        for (String stbr : values) {
            String reverse = "";
            for (int i = stbr.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                reverse += stbr.charAt(i);
            }
            if (reverse.equalsIgnoreCase(stbr)) {
                System.out.println("This is a Palindrome");
            } else {
                System.out.println("This is NOT a Palindrome");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

`for (String stbr : values) {` loops through every element in `values` one at a time, allowing you to reverse and check each element of your input.